# Как конвертировать array to list чтобы внутри list все значении были integer'ами?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql9.6

Дано:
data_array = {100003,100004,100005,100006,100007,100008} - содержания элементов неизвестны

Ожидаемый результат:
data_list = (100003,100004,100005,100006,100007,100008) (все int должны быть)

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно это сделать в postgresql?

Запрос:
select id, name from services
where id in data_list

заметка на нижний запрос (это не подходит для меня, мне нужно именно перевести на список):
select id, name from services
where id = ANY (data_array)

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос описание вашего кастомного типа данных list

Comment: Попробуйте `select id, name from services where id in(select unnest(data_array))`. Если я правильно догадался что имеется ввиду в вопросе ...

Comment: С unnest немного не то, что мне нужно выводит, пробовал до этого, спасибо за ответ.
Мне нужно чтобы, в одной ячейке выводил так : (100003,100004,100005,100006,100007,100008)(все int)

Answer (score 0):

## Пока не ответ:

```
select id, name from services
join unnest(data_array) c on id = c
```

> Так подойдет?

Если нет, распишите ситуацию подробней, и объясните какой тип данных, по Вашему мнению, должен быть у data_list (не у его элементов), а конкретно у `data_list`

Опять же, рассмотрите вариант с созданием функции отдающей в качестве результата `int[]`

## ИМХО

Вы пытаетесь решить часть задачи
неверно представляя алгоритм решения задачи.
Будет неплохо если Вы опишите всю задачу целиком